# Access points for AWS EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, posix, amazon-efs

I am trying to create access point for one of existing EFS.

After creating access point i want to mount it on a lambda fucntion.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "EFS ccess point cloudformation"
Resources:
  AccessPointResources:
    Type: AWS::EFS::AccessPoint
    Properties: 
      FileSystemId: Fs-xxx
      PosixUser: 
        Uid: "0"
        Gid: "0"
      RootDirectory: 
        Path: "/myefs"
```

Below is the error i am getting while deploying cloudformation.Please suggest what i am missing here

```
Model validation failed
/RootDirectorty/CreationInfo 3 schema violation found
/RootDirectorty/CreationInfo required [OwnerGid] not found
/RootDirectorty/CreationInfo required [OwnerUid] not found
/RootDirectorty/CreationInfo [permission] not found
```

Comment: Can you provide reproducible CFN template for the error?

Comment: @Marcin i am using exact CFN template given above with same parameter values.

Comment: It is not reproducible. No one can just copy and paste it to try to replicate the issue.

Comment: @Marcin I have updated the CFN in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide [CreationInfo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-efs-accesspoint-rootdirectory.html#cfn-efs-accesspoint-rootdirectory-creationinfo). You can try:

```
Resources:
  AccessPointResources:
    Type: AWS::EFS::AccessPoint
    Properties: 
      FileSystemId: Fs-xxx
      PosixUser: 
        Uid: "0"
        Gid: "0"
      RootDirectory: 
        CreationInfo:
          OwnerGid: "708798"
          OwnerUid: "7987987"
          Permissions: "0755"      
        Path: "/myefs"
```

Comment: How to get OwnerGid,OwnerUid details.

Comment: Ye its was very helpful indeed.Thanks!

Comment: @AWS_Lernar No problem. Glad could help.